# PHP HTML E-Mail will not send because of equal symbol any ideas?

Tags: php, html, email

I am using the following headers

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
```

When ever I try to format my message in html it works great until I add an "=" sign (for defining classes and href's ) when the script execute, it crashes for some reason and the email never gets sent.

Any ideas?

*Edit*
Someone asked for the code

```
$mysubject = "XXXXXXXXX"; 
$greeting = "Dear ".$x.","."<br><br>" ;    


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: X <x@x.com>';

$message = "
<h2>My Heading</h2>
<b>information here about what I want to say.</b>
<br><br>
<b>title: </b>".$myvar."
<br><br>
<b>title2: </b><a href=\"test.com\" >my test</a>
<br><br>";

$close = "<br><br>Thanks, "."<br><br>"."XX"."<br><br>"."http://x.com" ;

// mail function
mail($email.',',$mysubject, $greeting.$message.$close,$headers);
```

Comment: Please post more code. There's nothing in this above that would cause problems. Probably a quoting issue somewhere.

Comment: Try `$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";`

Comment: Why the trailing comma appended to `$email`? `$email . ','`

Comment: And if _it crashes_, what errors are reported? Turn on `display_errors` with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Michael, I have been meaning to take that out, even after I did still no luck with it being sent.

Comment: When I run ini_set all that gets echoed out is "11"

Comment: Is this all of the actual code? Specifically, I am betting on improper quoting or concatenation somewhere inside `$message` that we don't see above.

Comment: I swear that's what I am running in the var $message ... it works only when I take out the "=" which is bizarre to me since it should be seeing it as something that should be echoed not a piece of code. My editor is also not finding any errors.

Comment: Found out what was going on ... it was being sent out properly, it's just since the email had a hyper link in it gmail was sending it to my spam folder. This presents another challenge but at least I know whats going on now.

Comment: Don't build your own mime emails. Just use swiftmailer or phpmailer and save yourself a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 2):

You should choose (and understand) a `Content-Transfer-Encoding`:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable says:

> QP works by using the equals sign "=" as an escape character. It also
>   limits line length to 76, as some software has limits on line length.

Example from an email, it has both a charset AND an encoding defined. The `=` char is encoded to `=3D`, broken lines finish with a closing `=`:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="ISO-8859-2"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/htm=
l4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>WWF h=EDrlev=E9l</title>
<meta http-equiv=3D"content-type" content=3D"text/htm; charset=3DISO-8859-2=
" >
```